# KafkaStream createTopic not respecting Kafka server's auto.create.topics.enable settings

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a production Kafka cluster which recently got polluted with a bunch of new topics. The Kafka cluster has the following settings:

```
auto.create.topics.enable=false
delete.topic.enable=false
```

Upon investigation, I found that these topics were created by a client team who is using `KafkaStream`'s createTopic method:
`org.apache.kafka.streams.integration.utils.EmbeddedKafkaCluster#createTopic(java.lang.String, int, int)`

Does this imply that KafkaStream's topic creation doesn't go through the Server side broker setting of `auto.create.topics.enable`? Does this mean that the `createTopic*` methods do not count as auto-topic creation? If so, how can we stop client teams from programmatically creating topics on a Kafka cluster?

edit: the kafka cluster is running 10.1.1 and the client is running 1.0.0 for both Kafka and Kafka-Stream

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The config `auto.create.topics.enable` only applies if a client tries to read/write from/to a non-existing topic (or queries for metadata for a non-existing topic).

Kafka Streams, does create topic explicitly with a `CreateTopic` request and thus `auto.create.topics.enable` does not apply.

You can set up some ACLs for your cluster to control who can create topics: https://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html#security_authz

> Note: if you disallow the team that uses Kafka Streams to create new topics, you make it very hard for them to use Kafka Streams. Kafka Streams cannot operate without those topics and you are required to create those topics manually (with correct configurations) to not break the Kafka Streams application.